# ffmpeg -vf transpose not working for output as .mp4 file

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I want to rotate iPhone/iPad video to 90 degree, i am using following code

```
$input = 'video1.mp4';
$output = 'output.mp4';

$command = "ffmpeg -i $input -vf transpose=1 $output";
exec( $command, $ret );
```

the above code is not working for

```
$output = 'output.mp4'; //(mp4 file)
```

but its working fine when i use

```
$output = 'output.avi'; //(avi file)
```

Please tell me solution for this i want also compress video in mp4 video.

Comment: Which version of ffmpeg are you using?

Comment: ffmpeg version 2.1.git

Comment: Does that ffmpeg command work if you run it manually from the command line?

Comment: No, same command ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -vf transpose=1 output.mp4 is also not working on command line but .avi output is working.

Comment: Thanks! for showing me ray of light :). The Actual Command is "ffmpeg -y -i $input -strict experimental -acodec aac -vf transpose=1 $output"

Comment: — You should post that as an answer and mark it as correct if it worked.

Comment: You should always include the complete `ffmpeg` console output. It will say what the issue is.